# FB.getLoginStatus takes a really long time to respond

Tags: javascript, facebook

Running FB.getLoginStatus on a mobile device takes about 15 seconds to respond. Is this normal? Can I speed this up or find another way to retrieve this information?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

the status is given on the statusChange event :

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);
FB.init({ 
     appId:applicationID, cookie:false, status:true, xfbml:true,oauth : true 
});
```